# Bulk replace string in linux terminal

Tags: php, mysql, linux, server, centos

I have bunch of wordpress in my server, i need to change each of wordpress database host in wp-config.php file, how i do it using terminal?

current value

```
define( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1' );
```

need to change to

```
define( 'DB_HOST', 'dbserver.com' );
```

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible, you need to use the following command, also for multiple file you can create simple script with locations of the wp-config.php files.

```
sed -i 's/define( "DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1" );/define( "DB_HOST", "dbserver.com" );/g' wp-config.php
```

**Explanation:**

`sed` = Stream Editor

`-i` = in-place (i.e. save back to the original file)

The command string:

1. `s` = the substitute command
2. `define( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1' );` = a regular expression describing the string to replace (or just the string itself)
3. `define( 'DB_HOST', 'dbserver.com' );` = the text to replace it with
4. `g` = global (i.e. replace all and not just the first occurrence)
5. `wp-config.php` = the configuration file name

This answer is taken from [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands)